# How to set texmaker when upgrading from MacTeX 2017 to 2018?

Tags: texmaker, mac, mactex, paths, update

I am a frequent reader of tex.stackexcnage, this is my fist post and, since English is not my native language, I hope you will forgive my clumsiness.

I've been using fo several months texmaker on MacOS Sierra (10.12) with the MacTeX 2017 distribution. I would like to upgrade to the 2018 distribution and my question is :

How do I set texmaker to make it work with the new distribution ? Is there an easy solution without typing all the paths ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your texmaker preferences, e.g. this window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kedj5.png ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything.  Have you tried it? The way MacTeX is set up, the paths should not change; the actual paths are handled behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have not tried it yet. Should I remove the 2017 distribution before installing the new one ? If the two distributions are installed, how texmaker will know which one to use ?

Comment: No, you don't need to remove the 2017 distribution, and in fact I wouldn't recommend doing so immediately.  MacTeX automatically makes the most recently installed version the one that will be used, and you can use TeX Live Utility to switch between them. Your editor will use whichever one is currently selected. So if you install MacTeX 2018, TeXMaker will automatically use that provided the preferences are already set correctly.  See [texmaker not quick building :Mac with latest updates texmaker, mactex, miktex](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/407869) for what they should look like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments